# How way to use Process Ring on gridview on unversial app?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, win-universal-app

```
private async void GridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

xaml:

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="False" Visibility="Visible" Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
<GridView Name=""GridView" Loaded="GridView_Loaded">
      <GridView.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="8">
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
           </GridView.ItemsPanel>

              <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                 ...........................

</GridView>
```

**How way to use Process Ring on gridview on unversial app?** not each items.

And **How to binding** **"MaximumRowsOrColumns="8"** on code? I want to changed it on code.